# Typescript overload or generics to return different properties based on interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there any way to return different properties based on the interface type of the parameter?

What I need:

I have two interfaces that differ only on the name of one of the properties:

```
export interface img1 {
  id: number;
  apId: number; //requested property from this type
  img: string;
}

export interface img2 {
 id: number;
 artId: number;  //requested property from this type
 img: string;
}
```

Something like:

```
function childId(obj: img1|img2): number {
   return typeOf(obj)==='img1' ? artId : apId
}
```

Or maybe I should use Generics??

In this example there are only two interfaces but, with the same schema, I need to deal with five of them on my project.

**EDIT**

I have posted a stackblitz example where @jcalz is shown using a switch-case statement to hold more interfaces than two:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whciuy

Comment: You can't detect interface type at runtime because interfaces are [erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JS. Ideally you would make your types a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAmAWwOYEZkG8BQyyYAngA4QBcyAROtjQNzID0LxcGhqAJtSAFc0AI2iNucMgEk+yQSLH4AvvlCRYiFPQBMebqQrU6mbU1bswnbsFnzRUcUThQwM-kPviVMASARhgAHsQZAQAC2AAGx4ZAApA4QAranocAB9UEwBKdwUoPSIoCDABKBCExIA6AxQAXnrkAHIdRuQAfmQKyudXHmRqLskZZSA).

Comment: Or you might be able to define your types like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtgcwDwGkoQB7AgOwCYDOUA1hCAPYBmUAhjiAHxQC8UA3gFBRQCWeAXFBwBXOACMIAJwDcXXokEFgknjgSyAvlABkUAEoQAxuUl5UAGiGiJkhrMrCch4D3I4ohgBY8ANnhh4ABTkYgBWgvDIAEQ0YAFRTAA+sIhIMZLA8QwAlIIi4lLscpIQwMKS7umZeFG87iGhUAD8UA0AdDQZAVCC7bEBHBpAA) and use an `in` type guard.  I'm not sure what your use case requires though, so I'm not sure how best to advise.  This version should scale to 5 easily enough, but I'd prefer a [mcve] to be confident in my answer.

Comment: if @jcalz comment was posted as answer I'll have to mark it as the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` won't do what you want here, not least because `img1` and `img2` are interfaces which have no representation at runtime; Typescript will remove their declarations at compile-time. I can think of three approaches which will work for the general case (i.e. not just two interfaces in the union).

---

### 1. Check which property the object has

The `in` keyword can be used to test if an object has a property. If we assume that the union is disjoint - i.e., no object will implement more than one of the interfaces - then the following code works:

```js
function childId(obj: img1 | img2): number {
    if ('apId' in obj) {
        return obj.apId;
    } else if ('artId' in obj) {
        return obj.artId;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Illegal argument');
    }
}
```

---

### 2. Use a discriminated union

This requires changing the interfaces, but the code is neater and you get more type-safety, in that an object will not be able to implement more than one interface in the union.

```js
interface img1 {
    __tag: 'img1';
    id: number;
    apId: number;
    img: string;
}

interface img2 {
    __tag: 'img2';
    id: number;
    artId: number;
    img: string;
}

function childId(obj: img1 | img2): number {
    switch (obj.__tag) {
        case 'img1': return obj.apId;
        case 'img2': return obj.artId;
        default: throw new Error('Illegal argument');
    }
}
```

---

### 3. Polymorphic classes

The "proper" object-oriented solution would be to make `childId` a method, which each object can have a different implementation of, depending on its type. This requires more substantially changing the interfaces so that they are classes.

```js
class Img1 {
    constructor(public id: number, public apId: number, public img: string) { }
    public childId(): number {
        return this.apId;
    }
}

class Img2 {
    constructor(public id: number, public artId: number, public img: string) { }
    public childId(): number {
        return this.artId;
    }
}
```

Then you would call `obj.childId()` instead of `childId(obj)`.

Comment: By far the most complete and clear explanation. Even including the PROPER option! Thanks kaya3, people like you make this a great site.

Answer (score 1):

Define a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to help distinguish your two types at runtime:

```
function isImg1(obj: img1 | img2): obj is img1 {
    return 'apId' in obj;
}

function childId(obj: img1 | img2): number {
    return isImg1(obj) ? obj.apId : obj.artId;
}
```

In this particular case, the check can be inlined since that truly is all that's needed to distinguish the two allowed types in the parameter:

```
function childId(obj: img1 | img2): number {
    return 'apId' in obj ? obj.apId : obj.artId;
}
```

Comment: It is a good solution for two interfaces but, even the code is about two, at the bottom of the post I've detailed my particular case about 5 or more.